# R get difference per time-unit

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I want to make some graphs about electricity usage. I have a couple of big files, containing a timestamp and a (cumulative) measurement. I'd like to have three types of graphs:

- Usage per hour of a day
- Usage per day of a week
- Usage per month of a year

To do eg the usage per hour of a day I need to:

- Get usage of every hour of each day
- Average each hour of each day

The data I have is as follows:

```
2014-10-22 21:07:03+00:00,7432442.0
2014-10-22 21:07:21+00:00,7432443.0
2014-10-22 21:07:39+00:00,7432444.0
2014-10-22 21:07:57+00:00,7432445.0
2014-10-22 21:08:15+00:00,7432446.0
2014-10-22 21:08:33+00:00,7432447.0
2014-10-22 21:08:52+00:00,7432448.0
2014-10-22 21:09:10+00:00,7432449.0
2014-10-22 21:09:28+00:00,7432450.0
```

I'm able to load in the data and parse the timestamp with `as.POSIXct()`. I also know `diff()` is to get a difference. But how do I apply this to an entire data table?

Also, what happens with data in-between times? For example:

```
2014-10-22 23:59:54+00:00,7433033.0
2014-10-23 00:00:12+00:00,7433034.0
```

1 unit of something was used between the 22nd and the 23rd. Should this just be discarded, or added to one or the other?

Comment: I would suggest you look at `?cut.POSIXt` and `?seq.POSIXt` for ways to group your data into time periods.

Comment: if the problem is diff: 

    data(mtcars)
    mtcars$diff = c(0, diff(mtcars$mpg))

Comment: I'm sorry; what is the second column? When you say you want to plot usage, is that what is represented in the second column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the dummy dataset

```
# sorted dataset
n = 1000
set.seed(1)
data = data.frame(
  time=seq(as.POSIXct('2014-10-22 21:07:00'),
           as.POSIXct('2014-10-23 10:07:00'),
           length.out=n),
  value=cumsum(runif(n))/n)
```

we could calculate the change in value by hour of the day using

```
# by hour of a day
starttime = as.POSIXct(format(min(data$time),'%Y-%m-%d'))
endtime = as.POSIXct(format(max(data$time),'%Y-%m-%d'))+60*60*24
hod = with(data,
           c(by(value,
              cut(time,seq(starttime,endtime,'hour')),
              function(x)x[length(x)]-x[1])))
```

and then plot the results by doing

```
# plot
plot(as.POSIXct(names(hod)), hod, type='l')
barplot(hod)
```

[image: plot(as.POSIXct(names(hod)), hod, type='l')]
[image: barplot(hod)]

**Edit**:

Aggregating across days can be done with

```
# average across days of the total usage within each hour
hod_m = c(by(hod,
             format(as.POSIXct(names(hod)),'%H'),
             mean,na.rm=T))
```

Rather than calculating total usage within each day--hour, you can calculate 'average' usage per observation within each day--hour using

```
# average usage per observation within each hour of each day
au = with(data,
           c(by(value,
                cut(time,seq(starttime,endtime,'hour')),
                function(x)(x[length(x)]-x[1])/(length(x)-1))))
```

and the latter measures of average usage per observation can be aggregated across days by hour using

```
# average across days of the above average usage within each day--hour
au_m = c(by(au,
            format(as.POSIXct(names(hod)),'%H'),
            mean,na.rm=T))
```

Similarly, aggregation functions other than `mean` can be used in the above.

Comment: Very nice! How about getting the average of all hours of all days, so all values from 1:00 to 1:59 of every day averaged?

Comment: You could try `c(by(hod,format(as.POSIXct(names(hod)),'%H'),mean,na.rm=T))`